# vis.js - accessing whole node properties only by node id

Tags: properties, vis.js

could you give me a hint how I could access the whole properties of a node only by its ID. I mean all the information I get  when I would do for example `network.on("click", function(properties) {});` or something similar.

Finally I want to get the node IDs of all nodes that are connected to a specific node that I access by its ID. Is there a pre-defined function?

Thank you very much!!
Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

Use [dataset](http://visjs.org/docs/data/dataset.html):

```
var nodeId = 2;

var node = data.nodes.get( nodeId )
console.log(node);

var connected = data.edges
                    .get({
                          filter: function(item) {
                            return (item.from === nodeId) || (item.to === nodeId);
                          }
                    })
                    .reduce(function(ids, item){
                          var id = item.from;
                          if (id === nodeId) id = item.to;
                          ids.push( id );
                          return ids; 
                    }, []) 
console.log(connected);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jgh1ncxh/